# BigQuery error GoogleCredential C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

Using the code that Google makes available on github I was doing a test to upload files to the bigquery using C#, put in one of the tests showed an error in own google code.

```
GoogleCredential credential =
GoogleCredential.GetApplicationDefaultAsync().Result;
```

It appeared this error "System.AggregateException"

The class complete

```
static public BigqueryService CreateAuthorizedClient()
    {
        GoogleCredential credential =
            GoogleCredential.GetApplicationDefaultAsync().Result;
        // Inject the Bigquery scope if required.
        if (credential.IsCreateScopedRequired)
        {
            credential = credential.CreateScoped(new[]
            {
                BigqueryService.Scope.Bigquery
            });
        }
        return new BigqueryService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = "DotNet Bigquery Samples",
        });
}
```

Someone could help me solve this problem.

thanks.

Comment: Assuming the AggregateException is called e, what is the value of e.InnerException.ToString()?

Comment: If this is still an issue, could you give details about how you expected the default application credentials to be provided? (Environment variable, gcloud sdk, running on GCP.)

Answer (score 0):

I usually see this when you're not authenticated correctly. Try running "gcloud beta auth application-default login" first before running that code.